# Cannot debug Nodejs with node-inspector: websocket_closed and Assertion failed: Unknown experiment canvasInspection

Tags: node.js, debugging

I try to debug my server.js app with node-inspector (v0.12.8), nodejs (v5.9.1) and chrome (v49.0.2623.112 m) under windows environment.
In a shell i do

```
node-inspector   
Node Inspector v0.12.8 Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

In a second shell i do

```
node --debug server.js
```

When i go to chrome tab i obtain a message:

> Detached from target
>       remote debug has been terminated with reason: websocket_closed
>       please reattach to the new target

In the console dev tool of chrome i can see either a message that inspector can't find experimental function canvasInspection (removed in the latest chrome version).
I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I was having the same issue. And couldn't solved it. I even tried going backward few version on node inspector. After that I just installed visual studio community and it works fine.

Comment: I'm curious what the last working version of node-debug was

Answer (score 5):

Not the answer specifically, but as of Node v6, you can actually just use the `--inspect` flag when you start a process, and it will let you use the Chrome debugging tools instead of relying on node-inspector.  Check it out:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I fixed it the way below:

1- Go and edit the following file in your currently in use nodejs path:

```
 ...\node_modules\node-inspector\lib\InjectorClient.js
```

2- Go to `line 111`. if you're using vim as text editor you can do it by command `:111`

3- Add the following `if` statement at `line 111` and indent the next line.

```
if(NM.length > 0) 
  cb(error, NM[0].ref);
```

4- Save and re-run `node-inspector`.

Cheers!

I'm using MacOS Sierra, Node v6.3.1. But the solution is general.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue , but after lots of googling and finding about this issue. The only thing work for me is listed below :

1. Open your Command Promp(cmd) & type node -v, it will show you the version of node installed on your machine.
2. If the installed version is something 5.x.x or 6.x.x , then proceed further.
3. just uninstall this node version from control panel.
4. Install the node release with version 4 . I've tested with Node version v4.5.0 & I hope it will work fine for all Node with version v4.x.x.
5. Uninstall the previous node-inspector with command `npm uninstall node-inspector -g`.
6. Then Install again with command `npm install node-inspector -g`.
7. Then start debugging .. :)